# HEDA Apex Trigger is not executing from test class

Tags: apex, trigger

I am facing problem executing TDTM Trigger from Apex test class.

I have setup the below logic in @testSetup

```
List<hed.TDTM_Global_API.TdtmToken> tokens = hed.TDTM_Global_API.getTdtmConfig();
tokens.add(new hed.TDTM_Global_API.TdtmToken('Interest_LeadHandler_TDTM', 'Interest__c', 'AfterInsert;AfterUpdate;BeforeInsert;BeforeUpdate', 1.00));
hed.TDTM_Global_API.setTdtmConfig(tokens);
```

In my Interest_LeadHandler_TDTM class, I put the System.Debug statement in BeforeInsert context.
The same code is working fine in one org, but failing in another org. Any idea if there is anything I need to perform in Org for TDTM?

FYI - System Admin profile is having access to all Apex classes including heda classes.